# Inserting data into MySQL table from command line

Tags: mysql

I'm quite new to MySQL but I can't find out why I'm not able to import a csv file into my database from command line. Input file is too big for PHPMyAdmin and then I try to update the data table from the command line.

This is the command run from the terminal

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "/home/meteo/PROJECTES/BASE-AEMET/TREBALL/PCP.csv" into TABLE precipitacion FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (CodigoEst, Fecha, Precipitacion, ValidPP);
```

and these is the structure of the PCP.csv file

```
"7034",2000-01-01,0,"S"
"7034",2000-02-01,0,"S"
"7034",2000-03-01,0,"S"
"7034",2000-04-01,0,"S"
"7034",2000-05-01,0,"S"
```

But the output of the sql query gives this message

> Query OK, 0 rows affected, 65535 warnings (30,55 sec) Records: 1586445
>   Deleted: 0  Skipped: 1586445  Warnings: 4759335

and no records are inserted in the table.

When looking at warnings I get this message

```
mysql> SHOW WARNINGS \G                                               
*************************** 1. row ***************************   
Level: Warning    Code: 1265 Message: Data truncated for column 'CodigoEst' at row 1
*************************** 2. row ***************************
   Level: Warning    Code: 1265 Message: Data truncated for column 'ValidPP' at row 1
*************************** 3. row ***************************
   Level: Warning    Code: 1062 Message: Duplicate entry '"7034-2000-01-01' for key 'PRIMARY'
*************************** 4. row ***************************
   Level: Warning    Code: 1265 Message: Data truncated for column 'CodigoEst' at row 2
*************************** 5. row ***************************
   Level: Warning    Code: 1265 Message: Data truncated for column 'ValidPP' at row 2
*************************** 6. row ***************************
   Level: Warning    Code: 1062 Message: Duplicate entry '"7034-2000-02-01' for key 'PRIMARY'
*************************** 7. row ***************************
   Level: Warning    Code: 1265 Message: Data truncated for column 'CodigoEst' at row 3
*************************** 8. row ***************************
   Level: Warning    Code: 1265 Message: Data truncated for column 'ValidPP' at row 3
*************************** 9. row ***************************
   Level: Warning    Code: 1062 Message: Duplicate entry '"7034-2000-03-01' for key 'PRIMARY'
*************************** 10. row ***************************
   Level: Warning    Code: 1265
```

How to proceed? May it is an easy question but I'm stuck here. Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT 1

Add output suggested in comment by @jacktherandom

```
mysql> show CREATE TABLE precipitacion
    -> ;
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table         | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| precipitacion | CREATE TABLE `precipitacion` (
  `CodigoEst` char(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Fecha` date NOT NULL,
  `Precipitacion` decimal(5,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ValidPP` enum('N','S','A') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  PRIMARY KEY (`CodigoEst`,`Fecha`),
  KEY `Grupos_CodigoEst` (`CodigoEst`),
  KEY `Grupos_Fecha` (`Fecha`),
  KEY `Grupos_ValidPP` (`ValidPP`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Comment: Could you also post what the table schema is like? (The result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE precipitacion` query)

Comment: Why not read the messages and determine whether you are happy with them? e.g. are you OK with the data truncation? are you OK with duplicates? If not, revise your imported data and/or schema and start again.

Comment: @underscore_d I'm happy with warnings about not updating duplicates but new data should be inserted in the table. Not sure about data truncation. File with data has been build with the same R script than was previously used to format original data to table structure. Should work as it had worked before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the solution to importing data to my database was to split the original big csv into smaller files. Then, importing from phpMyAdmin ran fine.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The `Code: 1265 Message: Data truncated for column` means you are inserting a value that is larger in size than the column allows.

The `Code: 1062 Message: Duplicate entry` means you are inserting a value for a column that has a `UNIQUE` key, and that value already exists in another row for that column.

Comment: Regarding the 1062, I understand the message but I know there are new entries that should be inserted. Should I use something like `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`?

Comment: Yeah that might solve your problem here depending on the type of query. Give that a shot and see how it goes.